# Visual representation of type II error

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I doing some stats exercises, in which i have to calculate the Type II error for an normal distribution.

I understand the concept of it, that you accept $H_0$ even though it's not the true means, but i am having a hard time  understanding what part of the normal distribution i have to calculate.

I think i need some visual representation to understand why 
$$\beta = P(z < \frac{\bar{x_l} -µ_{true}}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}) - (1-P(z < \frac{\bar{x_h} -µ_{true}}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}))  $$

is given by this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do a simple Z-test of a single mean:

Picture a bell curve with the usual 1.96 rejection region around the null hypothesis (usually $\mu=0$). Now, *if* the null hypothesis is incorrect, then the true distribution is assumed to be a normal distribution with a different value of $\mu'$.

So, lets say that $\mu'=1$: what is the probability that this distribution will "fool" your test? Its exactly the probability that this shifted normal variable will fall in your "do not reject" region.

Visually: A type I error looks at the probability contained outside the "do not reject" region, as calculated with the null distribution.

The Type II error is exactly the opposite: you are calculating the probability of falling **in** the "do not reject" region but with a $non-null$ distribution.

Comment: hmm.. ok that makes some sense, but why standardize the boundary for the true mean, i would think that not the whole distribution for the true will be the part we won't to calculate...??

Comment: @Stats you don't have to, I was just offering a simple example with real numbers. The general idea is the same for any hypothesis test.

Comment: why does equation say so?

Comment: @Stats it makes the equation more convenient. The probability function being used is implicitly that of the standard normal.